# TSQL Query Indexes by date to determine when created?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way in SQL Server 2008 R2 to determine when an index was created via TSQL?  The sys.indexes table does not have any date fields on it.  Thanks.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2707/sql-server-index-creation-date

Comment: Thanks.  That basically says "you can't do it" but I was hoping someone may have found another way to figure it out, even if it isn't by date, if you could see the last 10 created or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can join it to sys.objects, which has a create_date field.

```
SELECT TOP 10
        *
FROM    <yourdb>.sys.indexes i
        INNER JOIN <yourdb>.sys.objects o ON i.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE o.type NOT IN ('S', 'IT')
ORDER BY create_date DESC
```

Re-edit-the-edit: I shouldn't attempt to communicate before I've had my morning coffee.

The same caveats to that answer linked apply, as they're not actually the creation date of indexes, but related objects.

If that is something that you need to be able to do, you could log the DDL statements:

http://madhuottapalam.blogspot.ca/2008/06/faq-how-to-find-index-creation-rebuild.html

Comment: While this may be of use to the asker, it should be noted that these dates will be the creation dates of the **tables**, rather than the indexes.

Comment: Yes, I did do the research and found the logging example.  I guess the answer is simply that SQL Server does not keep track of the date/time when indexes were created.  Is that the consensus?

Comment: It seems that way, I can't find anywhere indicating otherwise for any version of SQL Server. Just for my own curiosity, what would you need with the creation date?